How to construct a family of $k$-regular bipartite graphs with connectivity $k$
Clearly, for any integer $k$, we can construct the complete bipartite graph $K_{k, k}$, which is both $k$-regular and has connectivity $k$. However, in this case, with $k$ fixed, I aim to construct a family of $k$-regular,  bipartite graphs with connectivity $k$ that are not simply $K_{k, k}$.
ChatGPT seems to be suggesting that I try using Cayley graphs or hypercubes, but I haven't fully understood how these constructions work yet.

Assume we drop the bipartite assumption for a moment -- do you know of any infinite class of graphs which are $k$-regular with connectivity $k$?

Nice tips. I also cannot answer it.

:) Here's what I got so far. For $G$ $k$-regular and $k$-connected, construct $G'$ by creating two copies of $V(G)$. $G'$ will be a bipartite graph, and we connect vertex $v$ on one side to vertex $w$ on the other side iff $vw \in E(G)$. This graph is $k$-regular and is (probably) $k$-connected if $|G|$ is large enough (I have a short proof written out, but haven't checked it yet.)

Okay, it seems like what you want is called the Hanary Graph. It looks like if you take $n$ to be even, you can always get a regular graph that is $k$-connected. I'll double check everything tomorrow and write out an answer if it all goes through.

Thank you. It’s worth writing that.

The case of $k=1$ is degenerate, so let $k\ge2$. For $k=2$, the family of all even cycles does the job.
For $k\ge3$, we can construct a family as follows. Let $F_k$ be the graph obtained from $K_{k,k}$ by removing the edges of a perfect matching. It is easy to verify that $F_k$ is $(k-1)$-connected using an induction argument with base case $F_3$, which is $2$-connected.
Now take $n\ge1$ copies of $F_k$, call them $F_k^{(i)}$. Add an edge from every right vertex of $F_k^{(i)}$ to the corresponding left vertex of $F_k^{(i+1)}$ in a cyclic (or periodic) fashion, where “corresponding” is with respect to the removed perfect matching. The graph so obtained is bipartite, $k$-regular, and $k$-connected. The $k$-connectivity follows from the $(k-1)$-connectivity of $F_k$.
This class of graphs includes $K_{k,k}$, which is obtained by setting $n=1$.
Here is a sketch for $k=3$.


Edit: explanation for $k$-connectivity
Let us remove $k-1$ arbitrary vertices from the final graph. Say $k_i$ vertices are removed from $i$th copy, so $k_1+\cdots+k_n = k-1$. Let me call the edges within a copy as internal and those between two adjacent copies as external. Here follow some observations:

Since every external edge is connected to a unique pair of vertices, to remove all external between two adjacent copies, one has to remove at least $k$ vertices. Since we removed only $k-1$ vertices, any two adjacent copies are still connected by an external edge.
If $k_i< k-1$ for all $i$, then $(k-1)$-connectivity of $F_k$ implies that each copy is still connected by internal edges. So the final graph is still connected and we are done.
If $k_i=k-1$ for some $i$ (which means no vertices are removed from other copies), then the $i$th copy could be “internally disconnected” but each of its remaining vertices is connected to $(i-1)$th or $(i+1)$th copy via external edges, so the final graph is still connected.

This proves that the final graph is $k$-connected.

I'm a bit confused.  Why do $k$
-connectivity follow from $(k−1)$
-connectivity of $F_k$? the It seems to me that in the final graphs, removing the two end-vertices corresponding to the matching in any $F^{(i)}_k$ will cause the graphs to become disconnected.

@licheng If you remove two end vertices of an edge in the matching in a copy, there are still other end vertices in that copy that are connected to other copies.

May be I misunderstand. Could you draw your graphs with $k=3$?

Sure, I’ll make a figure.

@licheng added a sketch for $k=3$.

@licheng I added an explanation for $k$-connectivity. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Here's another infinite family of graphs (I am adding this as another answer because it is unrelated to my other answer):
For any $k\ge 2$ and $n\ge k$, consider $2n$ vertices labelled $l_i$ and $r_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Add an edge from $l_i$ to $r_{(i+j-1) \mod n}$ for each $i$ and $1\le j\le k$. The resulting graph is bipartite and $k$-regular by construction. It is not too hard to show that it is also $k$-connected. For example, one can show that there are $k$ vertex-disjoint paths between any two vertices and use Menger's theorem.
When $n=k$, this boils down to $K_{k,k}$.
